# An indefinite article with proper noun

Tags: indefinite-article

> Review: Nest Hub (2nd gen) sleep tracking ushers in **a** radically more pervasive Google Assistant

It's the review title of [this media.](https://9to5google.com/2021/03/30/nest-hub-2nd-gen-hands-on/) Why is there an indefinite article 'a'? Because Google Assistant is a proper noun and it is not used as a common noun in the context I presume there should not be 'a'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually a fairly common idiom in English, especially in advertisements and news articles.  The implication is that the product is not unique---perhaps a new version every year, or perhaps it has been revamped.  But this is often applied to people as well.  Consider this print title:

"A New Donald Trump? Moving Holocaust Speech Wins Praise From Jews, Derision From Alt-right"

Of course the are referring to the same person, but they are implying something like the person has re-invented themselves or changed tactics.